# Alert Dialog personalizado com imagem Gif

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

Gostaria de saber como criar um *Alert Dialog* personalizado onde tivesse uma ImageView contendo um GIF.

Na minha Main.

```
imgAndroid = (Button) findViewByid (R.id.imagandroid);
imgAndroid.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.imagee);

anime = (AnimationDrawable) imgAndroid.getBackground;
anime.start();
```

Criei um Drawable

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/playum" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/playdois" android:duration="1000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/playtres" android:duration="1000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/playquatro" android:duration="1000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/playcinco" android:duration="1000"/>

</animation-list>
```

O codigo do meu Alert Dialog

```
 public void testedialog (View View){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoggif);
    //button que leva para o menu
    Button irum = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button111);
    irum.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.menu);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //button que manda para o proximo nivel

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button122);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.menu);
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });


    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Pode postar o código do layout `dialoggif`? E qual é o problema que está ocorrendo?

Comment: Aplicação ao iniciar da erro e não chega a ser executada.

Comment: Pode postar alguma descrição do erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do google, você não deveria colocar o "anime.start()" dentro do *onCreate()*, você deveria usar *onWindowFocusChanged* que será executado quando sua app estiver no foco do usuário.

De acordo com eles:

> It's important to note that the start() method called on the AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached to the window. If you want to play the animation immediately, without requiring interaction, then you might want to call it from the onWindowFocusChanged() method in your Activity, which will get called when Android brings your window into focus.

Segue o link para referência: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html